# Integrate an internet calendar on SharePoint Home

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, calendar, calendar-view

We are trying to integrate our PTO calendar from an internet calendar (so no Outlook) on our main SharePoint Modern site Home page.

Following this article [How to embed a modern calendar to a SharePoint page](https://sharepoint.handsontek.net/2021/01/10/embed-modern-calendar-sharepoint-page) we managed to embed the calendar but it constantly requests logins.

If we add the link directly it displays the file as text instead of a calendar format.

Is there a way we can display it in calendar form without it requiring login?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to embed the calendar view using embed web part anymore as SharePoint online out of the box [List web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-list-web-part-ef0a1b80-f8b3-443d-b04a-1e76c70b5537) now supports showing modern calendar list view.

Check detailed steps to add Modern Calendar view to a SharePoint Online page using List web part at: [Add Modern Calendar to a SharePoint Online page using List web part](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/10/21/add-modern-calendar-to-a-sharepoint-online-page-using-list-web-part/)

---

This feature is currently rolling out to targeted release tenants. You can check the roadmap of this feature at: [SharePoint: Calendar view in Lists web part](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/roadmap?&filters=&searchterms=70750)

If you want access to this feature earlier (before general availability / standard release), you can set targeted release in your tenant: [Set up the Standard or Targeted release options](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/manage/release-options-in-office-365)

---

Else, if you want to continue using `embed` web part until the feature is available generally, you can try settings `src` attribute of `iframe`  to absolute URL of calendar view in below format:

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName/Lists/ListName/ViewName.aspx
```

Example:

```
<iframe src="https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName/Lists/ContentScheduler/Calendar.aspx" width="100%" height="600"></iframe>
```

Follow this article for detailed steps: [Add Modern Calendar to a SharePoint Online page](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/01/15/add-modern-calendar-to-a-sharepoint-online-page/)

Comment: Hi Ganesh Sanap, thank you for your reply but I think I need to provide an extra clarification. 
The calendar we are trying to display is from an external website, so it is not part of SharePoint or any other Microsoft product.

Comment: If the external website is secured site then there is not much we can do from SharePoint side for this. Try adding your site in **HTML Field Security** from site settings as mentioned in article: [Allow or restrict the ability to embed content on SharePoint pages](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/allow-or-restrict-the-ability-to-embed-content-on-sharepoint-pages-e7baf83f-09d0-4bd1-9058-4aa483ee137b).